# PHP - HTML Table convert to CSV just works for ~ 700 rows

Tags: php, html, csv, mamp

I'm trying to convert HTML tables to CSV with my PHP-Script.

I have a lot of HTML files and each of them contains just one table with very simple structure

```
<table><th></th><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

The HTML tables in the different files have between 300 and 2000 rows. My PHP script converts all of them with about 800 rows in under a second to CSV and everything works. But the others (with 900 rows a more) don't work. I always get an empty CSV File with just "ï»¿" in it (opening it in Excel).

I run the script local on MAMP and the PHP error log says for that non-working files:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/convertcsv.php:29

Thats my single fucntion in convertcsv.php script which makes the whole conversion:

```html
function convertToCSV($input,$output) {

$newFileContent = "";

file_put_contents($output, $newFileContent);
echo "File created (" . $output . ")";

$table = file_get_contents($input);
$html = str_get_html($table);

//Generate the CSV file header
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Encoding: UTF-8");
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");

$fp = fopen($output, "w");
fwrite($fp,"\xEF\xBB\xBF");

foreach($html->find('tr') as $element) {
    $td = [];
    $kinder = $element->children();
    foreach( $kinder as $kind) {
        $td[] = $kind->plaintext;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $td, ';');
}

fclose($fp);

}
```

Line 29 is the foreach-Loop.

Maybe you know why the script does work perfectly with tables with up to ~ 800 rows and not with bigger ones?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. I just have to increase the MAX_FILE_SIZE in the included simplehtmldom.php - Greetings